# What is the purpose of Galileo (or other unremovable chips)

Tags: prototype, arduino-galileo

I know the Arduino is a nice quick and dirty prototyping board. You quickly test your idea, and if you want to proceed you can do so with AVRs.

Your options are:

1. Upload the program to Arduino, then remove the AVR chip and make a PCB (with the bootloader)
2. Start from scratch with AVR (not always feasible because many libs are in Arduino)

Now what is the purpose of a system that has processors that cannot be removed? For example the Arduino Galileo.

Sure, you can do many things with it, but bottom line, you cannot remove the processor and do something with it.

As an example, imagine you are prototyping a system you wish to, then, market and sell. That is feasible with the Arduino Uno family.

But what if you did in in Galileo? Even if it worked, you couldn't sell your system because you rely on the prototyping board. You cannot remove the processor.

Am i missing something?

Answer (score 3):

Edit: As Chris points out, this answer is more about the simple AVR Arduinos. For comment on the Galileo and other more complex MCUs, please refer to Chris' answer.

For Arduino compatibility you can program the Arduino boot loader into the microcontroller using the ICSP pins. You do not need a chip from an Arduino board, you just solder a blank one in. Once the boot loader is on there you can use the Arduino IDE to upload sketches via the UART.

It is not necessary to use the Arduino system to write programs. You include the Arduino library files in a normal C++ project in many different IDEs and use the avr toolchain to compile and avrdude to upload.

Update:

Here is an example of a board I just got back from PCBA. (The picture was sent by the PCB company for checking). Initially I made the board using an Arduino Pro Mini 3.3V, SD card breakout board, LSM303DHLC accelerometer breakout from Pololu, and Real Time Clock (RTC) breakout. Once everything was working I drew up a PCB in Eagle CAD, using the core of Arduino Pro Mini board plus the individual SD card, LSM303DLHC and RTC chips. I also added a 3.3V boost converter so I could get a constant 3.3V off 2 AA batteries.

[image]

The board has the ICSP pins broken out. Actually, you will find they are broken out on most Arduino boards. Using another [Arduino as ISP](http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ArduinoISP) I can program the Arduino boot loader via the ICSP pins, and then sketches can be uploaded via the UART using the Arduino IDE. In the IDE the board that is selected is "Arduino Pro Mini 3.3V 8MHz".

The Arduino boot loader is a small piece of firmware that runs on startup. It allows you to send a program over the UART which it stores into FLASH memory itself. It is not absolutely necessary. You can program the chip using the ICSP as well. It is really convenient however. Using software like [xloader](http://russemotto.com/xloader/) you can upload Arduino programs without the IDE. Really handy when other people are using the board and you don't want to share your code. Alternatively, you can write a script for avrdude to do it.

This project is for a university so I'm leaving it as Arduino compatible. In a commercial engineering environment, I would choose a more appropriate MCU (one with lower power consumption for a battery device) and rewrite the program to be more efficient and not rely on the Arduino and third-party libraries.

Comment: Would the drive-by down-voter care to explain? This answer is right on - I build projects exactly this way. I even prototype with an Arduino Mega 2560, then recompile for, and download to a bare ATMega328p on my project board. A few `#define`s manage the pin assignment differences. --
A compensating upvote from me.

Comment: thanks geometrikal and jRobert. never worked with the ISCP pins before, but it seems like a fairly easy process.

Comment: Not the downvoter, but worth noting that while this is a nice generic answer, it's mostly about the 1/2-layer suitable AVR based Arduinos.  The Galileo cited in the question is an x86 based computer module in a drastically different league of capability and manufacturing complexity.

Answer (score 1):

You are right. There are however people that use an arduino for hobby, and don't want to invest more time into learning to make PCB and programming bare AVRs. For some people getting some leds to blink is already very hard.

Also look at the amount of Arduino shields that are available. The target group of Arduino's has shifted from hobby electronics people to just regular people wanting to get some project working. People are okay with sacrificing an entire arduino board, adding some shields and putting it inside a Tupperware box. As long as it solves their problem, or does something cool.

Answer (score 1):

The pentium-class x86 based Galileo mentioned in the question title appears intended to meet project needs which have (memory, compute, or interface) requirements beyond the capability of the simple AVR (or perhaps even ARM) based Arduino boards.   It's not uncommon in the Arduino realm to see people trying to use the little processors for tasks which exceed their capability, and it appears intended to address that problem.

While one can breadboard the equivalent of the AVR based Arduinos, or duplicate the functionality of those or even the simpler ARM-based boards on a hobbyist-designed 2 layer PCB, implementing something like the Galileo would require a many-layer board designed by an experienced PCB designer.  **For low-volume uses, someone would probably just buy the existing boards and use them** (there is a longstanding market of embedded control modules intended for such use) - only at high volumes would it be cost effective to re-implement the board or its equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Arduino boards, with or without removable chips, provide a lot of facilities ready to go for experimenters, prototypers, students, artists and other tinkerers who aren't necessarily interested in the electronics but just want a programmable controller to get a job done. They can often be the cheapest way to build a one-off system once you consider the labor to build a less expensive board.

It's really easy to program AVR chips on a breadboard or, in most cases, right on the custom project board. You don't need Arduino to do that. I've built up and programmed ATMega328p projects without ever taking my Arduino out of the box.

This is a project I prototyped on an Arduino Mega2560 and later ported to the project board with soldered-in chip. The cable is a USB FTDI serial cable, a stock item that connects any chip with a TTL UART directly to a computer USB port. (The green daughter board is an X-10 RF transmitter and the reason I prototyped this project on a larger CPU).

[image]

Often I develop project code solely on the project board; it's just about as easy. About the only advantages I get from using the larger board is multiple serial lines so I don't have to keep switching my terminal app off and on to allow down loading, and I can include lots of extra debugging code and libraries that I won't need in the project.

Your favorite tool set will work either way. The Arduino IDE, Eclipse, or bare-nekkid ARVdude at the command line. If your project code needs the Rx/Tx pins, you may need to build one board with jumpers to disconnect the project's serial hardware while you're downloading.